# If Else not working within Method in Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Code is terminating at line 11 after asking question. It does run if statement. Program is not giving any error either.

```
class Car():

    def __init__ (self, name):
        print (f"Hello and welcome {name}. You have won a Ferrari. Please enter the details below. \n")
        phone = input("Your phone number: ")
        address = input("Your home address: ")

    def sorry(self):
        print ("Hey! We are sorry, we do not ship beyond 2000 Miles.")

        response = input("Do you still want it? Yes or No? : ".upper())

        if response == "YES":
            print (f"Cool! {name}. Ride to us.")
        elif response == "NO":
            print (f"Oops! {name}. We are sorry to see you go. :(")
        else:
            "Have a Good day!"


Car1 = Car("Jack")
Car1.sorry()
```

Comment: `input("Do you still...").upper()`

Comment: Issue is not in your if else statement you wrongly accessing  class name

Comment: On top of @Austin's comment.. The reason it isn't printing anything is there is no print statement in the `else`. It just makes a string `"Have a Good day!"` and does nothing with it.

Comment: You first upgrade Your oop concepts about class variable and instance variable access your instance variable by declaring it in init method

Comment: typecast your input Variable And then Upper and then compare

Comment: Please don't put a space between a function name and the open parenthesis. `print (` is bad form. It's like bench pressing with your legs in the air.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you save the user's input to an instance variable of the class and not just a local variable to the method.

`self.phone = input("Your phone number: ")`

2. Print the "Have a good day" response by calling `print`.
3. Never put a space between a function name and the open parenthesis.
4. all variable names should be lower case and possibly containing underscores.
5. Access the instance variable `self.name` inside the `sorry()` method, instead of just an null local variable `name`.

`print(f"Cool! {self.name}. Ride to us.")`

6. Make sure you capitalize the response to "Do you still want it? Yes or No? : " and not the question itself.

`response = input("Do you still want it? Yes or No? : ").upper()`

7. Make sure you save the user's name in the constructor, so that you can access it later.

`self.name = name`

Give this a try:

```
class Car():

    def __init__ (self, name):
        print(f"Hello and welcome {name}. You have won a Ferrari. Please enter the details below. \n")
        self.name = name
        self.phone = input("Your phone number: ")
        self.address = input("Your home address: ")

    def sorry(self):
        print("Hey! We are sorry, we do not ship beyond 2000 Miles.")

        response = input("Do you still want it? Yes or No? : ").upper()

        if response == "YES":
            print(f"Cool! {self.name}. Ride to us.")
        elif response == "NO":
            print(f"Oops! {self.name}. We are sorry to see you go. :(")
        else:
            print("Have a Good day!")

ca1 = Car("Jack")
ca1.sorry()
```

Answer (score 0):

You use upper function in wrong way,

correct way is this:

```
response = input("Do you still want it? Yes or No? :").upper()
```

,You forget to put "Have a good day!" in print function

```
  print("Have a Good day!")
```

,also you lack in OOPS concept ,initialize

```
    self.name=name
```

then you able to access name.

I rewrite your code and now it execute fine.Hope it help
        class Car():

```
        def __init__ (self, name):
            self.name=name
            print (f"Hello and welcome {name}. You have won a Ferrari. Please enter the details below. \n")
            phone = input("Your phone number: ")
            address = input("Your home address: ")

        def sorry(self):
            print ("Hey! We are sorry, we do not ship beyond 2000 Miles.")

            response = input("Do you still want it? Yes or No? :").upper()


            if response == "YES":
                print (f"Cool! {self.name}. Ride to us.")
            elif response == "NO":
                print (f"Oops! {self.name}. We are sorry to see you go (: ")
            else:
                print("Have a Good day!")


    Car1 = Car("Jack")
    Car1.sorry()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors in your code:

- `response = input("Do you still want it? Yes or No? : ".upper())` is not changing the user's input to uppercase but making your prompt string uppercase. So, change it to `response = input("Do you still want it? Yes or No? : ")`**`.upper()`**
- The `{name}` is throwing errors as the code does not know what name is. So, in your class, add `name` as a string attribute and in the `__init__` define the `name`. Later, use a placeholder string to attach the name to the print string.
- The last `else` statement lacks a `print()`

---

The modified class `Car` should look something like this:

```
class Car():
name = ""

def __init__ (self, name):
    self.name = name

    print (f"Hello and welcome {name}. You have won a Ferrari. Please enter the details below. \n")
    phone = input("Your phone number: ")
    address = input("Your home address: ")

def sorry(self):
    print("Hey! We are sorry, we do not ship beyond 2000 Miles.")

    response = input("Do you still want it? Yes or No? : ").upper()

    if response == "YES":
        print(f"Cool! %s. Ride to us." % self.name)
    elif response == "NO":
        print(f"Oops! %s. We are sorry to see you go. :(" % self.name)
    else:
        print("Have a Good day!")
```

Answer (score 0):

There a are a couple of problems:

### 1. Upppercase

In

```
response = input("Do you still want it? Yes or No? : ".upper())
```

you are applying `upper()` to the prompt text, not to the answer, given
that in the following your code only checks for `"YES"` and `"NO"` you should use:

```
response = input("Do you still want it? Yes or No? : ").upper()
```

where the `response` is converted to uppercase instead.

### 2. "else not working"

```
    else:
        "Have a Good day!"
```

may be we forgot `print` here? :-)